# return search results if enter button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have been struggling trying to trigger the button if enter button is pressed. I have tried trigger() and click() and no luck. I cannot figure out why it will not execute and the search button does work correctly when clicked with a mouse, but not when an enter button is pressed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    //alert("this");
    //$('#btnsearch').trigger('click');

$("#txtsearch").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#btnsearch").click();
    }
});
    $('#btnsearch').click(function(event) {
        var searchText = $('#txtsearch').val();
        $.ajax({

            url: domain + "",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function(data) {


              $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
                $('#tblResult tbody').append('<tr><td style="">' + '<a href = "' + item.Details + '">' + item.Title + '</td></tr>');


              }

            )};

          event.preventDefault();



        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <div id="" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="txtsearch" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button id="btnsearch" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: try `$('#btnsearch').on('click', function(event)`

Comment: check for error in console?

Comment: Your `input` and `button` elements are already in a form, so you should have this behaviour by default; you don't need to add any JS code to do what you need

Comment: Your event.preventDefault(); either should be inside ajax success function or outside ajax call. Bracket placement is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

As your `input` is already contained within a `form` element you get this behaviour by default, so the `keyup` handler is redundant.

The bigger issue you have is the several syntax errors in your code which you can see in the console when running the snippet in your question.

- You've included Bootstrap *before* jQuery. It has to be the other way around
- Your call to `preventDefault()` is inside the `$.ajax` settings object and causing a syntax error
- The `success` handler function in `$.ajax` isn't closed properly.

When you fix those issues it works fine:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.navbar-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var searchText = $('#txtsearch').val();

    $.ajax({
      url: domain,
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
          $('#tblResult tbody').append('<tr><td><a href="' + item.Details + '">' + item.Title + '</td></tr>');
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
  <div id="" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="txtsearch" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="btnsearch" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
      </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the event handler for pressing enter:

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

Edit: 
You should run your click in a function so you can reuse it for the 2 scenarios (keyup and click) like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    //alert("this");
    //$('#btnsearch').trigger('click');

  function submitSearch(){
    var searchText = $('#txtsearch').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: domain + "",
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
          $('#tblResult tbody').append('<tr><td style="">' + '<a href = "' + item.Details + '">' + item.Title + '</td></tr>');
        }
      )};
  }

  $('#btnsearch').click(function(event) {
    submitSearch();
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(event){
      submitSearch();
  });

});
```